# $|X|=|\mathbb{N}|$ for $X$ finite?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Consider a countable set $X$, which may or may not be finite (note: we define a countable set to be either finite or infinite). Is it necessarily true that a bijection exists from $X$ to $\mathbb{N}$ (i.e. is it true that $|X|=|\mathbb{N}|$) for finite $X$?

I know from definitions that if $X$ is countably infinite (i.e. countable and infinite), then $|X|=|\mathbb{N}|$. But I was also wondering if the same is true if $X$ is a finite set. My intuition thinks this is true, but I am looking for some clarity.

Comment: If $X$ is finite how could $\lvert X\rvert=\lvert\mathbb N\rvert$?

Comment: No, if $X$ is a finite set, then there is no bijection from $X$ to $\Bbb{N}$. This should be intuitive: if $X$ is finite, then it is clearly smaller than $\Bbb{N}$ (an infinite set).

Comment: If $X$ is finite, it corresponds to $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$, so $|X|=n$, whereas $|\mathbb N|=\aleph_0$

Comment: Ah, what a foolish mistake. Thank you all.

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking that if there is a surjection $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to X$ then there is an injection $g \colon X \to \mathbb{N}$ that is a *right inverse* to $f,$ i.e. $f \circ g$ is the identity on $X$? This is just one step away from $f$ and $g$ being a pair of mutually inverse bijections. Just a thought - sorry if it's irrelevant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true that a bijection exists from finite $X$ to $\mathbb N$. If you tried to construct one, you'd inevitably find that there are still infinitely many elements of $\mathbb N$ left after you mapped all the elements of $X$.

However if $X$ is countable, including finite, there always exists an *injection* to $\mathbb N$. That is, you can map each element to a different natural number. Or in other words, you can *count* the elements of $X$ (because counting is nothing else but assigning natural numbers). That's where the term countable comes from.

Answer (score 1):

No, If $X$ is finite then there is a bijection $f:X \to \{1,2,3...,n\} $ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.